# What is that extra benefit of using Telerik Grid Project Or Telerik UI Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am looking at the demo for Telerik Grid and The demo starts with having to create a Telerik Grid project /Telerik UI project. My problem here is that I am creating an MVC application which might have multiple Controllers and Views and most of them don't have anything to do with Telerik. So I do not want all unwanted stuff that "Telerik Project" might bring to my regular application. So what are my options?

- Not create a telerik project and manually add all the required libraries for Telerik?
- Create a Telerik project and let Telerik libraries be addred into my View/Controllers which may not have anything to do with Telerik?
- Do I have a way to selectively specify that which View Or Controller might need some help on Telerik Controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Telrik Projects is just a boiler plate or bootstrapped way of having all of the Telerik components ready for your project. You do not need to create Telerik Projects to use their components. You would simply create your APS.NET MVC Application and add a reference to their DLLs and/or add their controls into your project space. Once you have a reference to them in your Project you would use a 'using' statement in the controller where you were going to use them on.